# Is it okay to add off-site links to cross posted questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have noticed a few questions recently where the author of the question has manually added links to other Q&A sites on the internet where they have asked the identical question. I didn't think that was okay, and I edited the questions to remove the external links. However, my edits were rolled back almost immediately by the OP to restore the off-site links.

What is the policy about linking to identical questions asked on other Q&A sites?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be okay?

Comment: @guest: It feels to me like this is less useful than even a link-only answer. It's a link to the identical question on some other site. And the other site's standards for quality and discourse probably doesn't match that of Stack Exchange. There's no indication in the link whether there is even anything useful at the other end. I just don't see the value.

Comment: Hm, I do think that it doesn't decrease  the value of the question. One could just ignore it I think its at least as useful as to like to a duplicate question here. And yes, the other site's standards may be higher or lower than on this site, but  I would be really interested in more answer, if a question interests me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is ok. See the Meta.SE post: [Am I allowed to indicate crosspost links in my questions on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293150/178179)

Comment: Instead of useless page filling, pad out the answer with the reason you post those links, as you have posted at one of your questions.

Comment: @Willeke thanks I'm afraid that adding reasons will start some debate, whereas it has already been decided it is ok in Meta.SE anyway.